# Magento - difference between resource and mysql4

Tags: php, magento

can anybody tell me the difference between creating a model extending

```
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
```

and one extending

```
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
```

I noticed that for example Mage_Cms is using resource instead of Mysql4, and that in it's config file myslq4 is marked as deprecated but I can't find anything in the official phpdocs that mark mysql4 deprecated? 
I'm using Magento EE ver. 1.11.1.0

Comment: As of 1.6 Community Edition (I don't know about EE), Mysql4 was deprecated in favor of Resource

Comment: thanks for reply Max, if you post it as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of 1.6 Community Edition (I don't know about EE), Mysql4 was deprecated in favor of Resource

[See explanation pdf](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/RDBMS_Guide.pdf)

Comment: PDF link broken ... My question is whether we should use Mysql4 in future modules or not.